# Take object out of array based on attribute value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

My array looks like this:

```
array = [object {id: 1, value: "itemname"}, object {id: 2, value: "itemname"}, ...]
```

all my objects have the same attibutes, but with different values.

Is there an easy way I can use a WHERE statement for that array?

> Take the object where object.id = var

or do I just need to loop over the entire array and check every item? My array has over a 100 entries, so I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way

Comment: In what way is this a TypeScript question?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Use `Array.find`:

```
let array = [
    { id: 1, value: "itemname" },
    { id: 2, value: "itemname" }
];

let item1 = array.find(i => i.id === 1);
```

Array.find at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Thanks, this solution is the cleanest and it worked!

Comment: let item1 = array.find((i : any ) => i.id === 1);

Answer (score 14):

I'd use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
let array = [
    { id: 1, value: "itemname" },
    { id: 2, value: "itemname" }
];

let item1 = array.filter(item => item.id === 1)[0];
let item2 = array.reduce((prev, current) => prev || current.id === 1 ? current : null);

console.log(item1); // Object {id: 1, value: "itemname"}
console.log(item2); // Object {id: 1, value: "itemname"}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20array%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20value%3A%20%22itemname%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%202%2C%20value%3A%20%22itemname%22%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Alet%20item1%20%3D%20array.filter(item%20%3D%3E%20item.id%20%3D%3D%3D%201)%5B0%5D%3B%0Alet%20item2%20%3D%20array.reduce((prev%2C%20current)%20%3D%3E%20prev%20%7C%7C%20current.id%20%3D%3D%3D%201%20%3F%20current%20%3A%20null)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(item1)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Object%20%7Bid%3A%201%2C%20value%3A%20%22itemname%22%7D%0Aconsole.log(item2)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Object%20%7Bid%3A%201%2C%20value%3A%20%22itemname%22%7D))

If you care about iterating over the entire array then use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
let item;
array.some(i => {
    if (i.id === 1) {
        item = i;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20array%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20value%3A%20%22itemname%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%202%2C%20value%3A%20%22itemname%22%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Alet%20item%3B%0Aarray.some(i%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(i.id%20%3D%3D%3D%201)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20item%20%3D%20i%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0A%7D)%3B))

Comment: Array has a find() method that returns the first occurance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: @JánHalaša True, I forgot about that one, you should post that as an answer. I'll vote for it.

Comment: Using filter() is still a better way because it will catch multiple instances of the same value for the attribute. You can check the length to ensure there's only 1 instance.

Answer (score 7):

**You can search a certain value in array of objects using TypeScript dynamically if you need to search the value from all fields of the object without specifying column**

```
 var searchText = 'first';

let items = [
            { id: 1, name: "first", grade: "A" },
            { id: 2, name: "second", grade: "B" }
        ];

This below code will search for the value

var result = items.filter(item => 
             Object.keys(item).some(k => item[k] != null && 
             item[k].toString().toLowerCase()
             .includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
             );
```

Same approach can be used to make a Search Filter Pipe in angularjs 4 using TypeScript

Answer (score 4):

I had to declare the type to get it to work in typescript:

```
let someId = 1  
array.find((i: { id: string; }) => i.id === someId)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to loop over the array, but if you make a hashmap to link each id to an index and save that, you only have to do it once, so you can reference any objeft after that directly:

```
var idReference = myArray.reduce(function( map, record, index ) {
    map[ record.id ] = index;
    return map;
}, {});

var objectWithId5 = myArray[ idReference["5"] ];
```

This does assume all ids are unique though.

Comment: There is a Map class that could be used for making that more efficient data structure https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Definately. Looking forward to using it once we upgrade to IE Edge or decide to use modernizr. Reduce and such are supported more widely. The code to reference each object might be longer though, since you'll use .get() for it. For the OP that won't matte though, since it'll compile down to this structure anyway.