# Get all array/map entries that match string

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm working with two arrays that has correlated the values, which mean that `arrayX[1]` correlate with `arrayY[1]`, and `arrayX[2]` correlate with `arrayY[2]` and so on.

I now need to filter that arrayX, to match or contains a given value, and only displays the arrayX filtered and arrayY that matches.

I've tried to create an array/map with key - value that I found this link [Take object out of array based on attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580100/typescript-take-object-out-of-array-based-on-attribute-value), and then filter with '.find' but I couldn't has the expected result.

When I call the function to filter I pass a value, for example I'm passing a string `'2010'`

- My arrayX has:

  (10) ["Dec 2008", "Feb 2010", "Apr 2010", "Jul 2010", "Dec 2010", "Feb 2011", "Apr 2012", "Jul 2013", "Mar 2014", "May 2017"]
- My arrayY has:

  (10) [1, 7, 4, 1, 10, 11, 4, 8, 7, 10]

so, for the output I need

`arrayX` to be `["Feb 2010", "Apr 2010", "Jul 2010", "Dec 2010"`] and

`arraY` to be `[7, 4, 1, 10]`.

My typescript code that expects a value and filter is:

```
filtr(dt){
      console.log(dt);
      console.log(this.arrayX);
      console.log(this.arrayY);

      //Array contains x and y values at the correct position
      let array = [
          {y: this.Yvalues, x: this.Xvalues}
      ];

      let item : any = array.find(i => i.x.find(dt));

      //new filtered x and y values on array 
      console.log(item)
}
```

I can't figure out how am I going to do this... I thought that the key -> value was a good solution, but I can't even have an output..
Sorry if I'm missing something easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` and check if the provided value exist in the current date string. Then add the date and value corresponding to that index from the other array to your result array.

```js
const arrayX = ["Dec 2008", "Feb 2010", "Apr 2010", "Jul 2010", "Dec 2010", "Feb 2011", "Apr 2012", "Jul 2013", "Mar 2014", "May 2017"],
      arrayY = [1, 7, 4, 1, 10, 11, 4, 8, 7, 10],
      year = 2010,
      result = arrayX.reduce((r, date, i) => {
        if(date.includes(year)){
          r.push({x: date, y: arrayY[i]})
        }
        return r;
      },[]);
console.log(result);
```

To get the X and Y values separately, for chart purposes, for example, just map the result and iterate over it, like this.

```
let x = result.map(({x}) => x);
let y = result.map(({y}) => y);
```

Comment: Oh, we get index too!! Thanks! mine is way cumbersome than yours.

Comment: thank you friend! With this i can filter other types too right, like names, etc.. ?

Comment: Please share the sample output.

Comment: if instead of year i got names, i can filter the same way, right?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code snippet below.
You can use the returned result like: `result.newArrayX` and `result.newArrayY`. This way you will also keep the original arrays safe.

```js
arrayX =  ["Dec 2008", "Feb 2010", "Apr 2010", "Jul 2010", "Dec 2010", "Feb 2011", "Apr 2012", "Jul 2013", "Mar 2014", "May 2017"];

    arrayY =  [1, 7, 4, 1, 10, 11, 4, 8, 7, 10];

    function filterFunc(filterYear) {

        return this.arrayX.reduce((acc, elem) => {
                if (elem.split(' ')[1] == filterYear) {
                    acc.newArrayX.push(elem);
                    acc.newArrayY.push(this.arrayY[this.arrayX.indexOf(elem)])
                }
                return acc;
            },{newArrayX: [], newArrayY: []}
        );
    }

    result = this.filterFunc('2010');
    console.log(result);
```