# return value from .forEach() indise a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, foreach, return-value

I'm trying to make a return from a `.forEach()` inside a function, but it always return `'There is no book with this name'` even when the condition is true.

code:

```
function getBookByName(books:[], name: string): object | string {
   books.forEach((book) => {
        if (book.name === name) {
            return book
        }
    })
    return 'There is no book with this name'
}
```

Comment: This appears to be boiling down to ["How to find an element in an array and return it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580100/typescript-take-object-out-of-array-based-on-attribute-value). I don't want to mark it as a duplicate, but it may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function  takes another function (callback) as a parameter and ignores it's returned value, therefore your `return` never stops the execution.

> forEach() executes the callbackFn function once for each array element; unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.
>
> Note: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.

For this case it's better to use [array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const books = [ { name: "test" }];

function getBookByName(books, name){
  return books.find((book) => book.name === name) || 'There is no book with this name';
};

console.log(getBookByName(books, "test"));
console.log(getBookByName(books, "test2"));
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nA1lAvFA3gWAFBTwOwEMBbCALigGdgAnAS3wHMBuHAXxxwGM59qoARgkSUK8JAG0AuqigSMUIqQoAiYBGoqobKa2w4AZgFd8XYHV5RGEYOMQwQAORIQAFEKSjYw6QBpFLhTU9EwAlGLCUAA%20VLQMjBg4eDQ2RjT4gsKUAHQGDAAmru7CoagAfJlI2UrQKHUBpKVRMQDkACoAFhApUHSUinCVyADudMAdUON9DRAtemx63LyUcAA2ENmrcIyu1rbCDs6kxZ7%20ahrAKqGhejx8axtbO3t2hy4nImfq1ABMVzdAA)